# CouchDB list "An error occured accessing the list: Invalid JSON" error

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to call a CouchDB list from JavaScript.

My jQuery call is:

```
var listItems = $.couch.db('foo').list('foo/barList', 'foo/barView');
```

If I test this in the FireBug console when I'm on a page that has jquery.couch.js loaded (like Futon) it returns exactly what I want it to (several `<input>` tags with the appropriate data populated).

However, when I call this from code, I get the error:

```
An error occured accessing the list: Invalid JSON: [the html]
```

... where `[the html]` is the html I want to manipulate in my script. I don't understand why I'm getting a JSON error - I thought the point of lists was to return HTML. Is there a way to force it to return my html to me?

Also, my list function includes the following, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

```
    start({
      "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/html"
      }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1059 this was a recognized bug and it had been patched. However after making the changes in jquery.couch.js recommended by Jan Lehnardt on the above page, I had to do one thing further.

The page above recommends making the following change in jquery.couch.js :

```
- var resp = httpData(req, "json");
+ var resp = httpData(req, dataType);
```

For some reason this didn't work for me but it did when I instead replaced it with the following. Theoretically one could add handlers for different types of content-types below.

```
var cType = req.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
switch(cType) {
    case 'text/html':
        var resp = req.responseText;
        break;
    default:  
        var resp = $.parseJSON(req.responseText);
        break;
    }
```

If I'm missing something, I welcome recommendations on how to do this more effectively, but this works for me.